# List of individual JavaScript object to proper array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I've encountered a problem with conversion list of individual JavaScript object to proper JavaScript array.

The list looks like below:

```
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
```

So, as you can see there two things which I need to take care of:

1. Adding missing commas
2. Create array from it.

To parse this response I'm using node JS. I've tried to convert this to array as follows:

```
const array = `[${response.data}.replace(/}/g, '},')}{}]`
```

Firstly I'm wrapping everything with array, add commas, and one empty object to get rid of last unwanted comma.

If I look at output everything seems ok, but when I'm trying to parse it with `JSON.parse()` I'm receiving

> Unexpected ']' on position n

I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or that data is corrupted since it is so long.

Comment: Fix what the server returns, that should already be valid JSON.

Comment: It looks like you may be building your JSON manually server-side, you probably should instead build a proper array and use JSON encoding function to export it

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to add commas to the end of every line but the last, change `someArray` to `"someArray"`, then surround the whole string in `[]` and `JSON.parse` it:

```js
const response = `{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }`;

const json = '[' + response.replace(/}(?!$)/g, '},').replace(/someArray/g, '"$&"') + ']';
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(arr);
```

But this is still an X/Y problem - better to fix whatever's serving you that (effectively broken) data to get it to give you proper JSON instead, so that a hack like this isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to omit the last comma and look ahead if some more characters are coming.

```
const array = `[${response.data}.replace(/}(?=.)/g, '},')}{}]`;
//                                         ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot modify the response of this list, you can use this:

```
const array = response.data.split(/\r?\n/).map(object => JSON.parse(object.replace("someArray", "\"$&\"")));
```

Each line will be split by `split(/\r?\n/)` and `replace("someArray", "\"$&\"")` will add the missing double quotes around `someArray`.

Working example:

```js
const response = {
  "data": `{ "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
           { "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
           { "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
           { "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }
           { "property1": "value", someArray: [123], "property2": [] }`
}

const array = response.data.split(/\r?\n/).map(line => JSON.parse(line.replace("someArray", "\"$&\"")));

console.log(array);
```